# Docker Meteor development setup still connecting to local database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a docker-compose setup for my meteor app. the docker-compose is this

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: docker/web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/meteor/app
    container_name: newkeyz-web
    links:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor
    command: ["meteor","npm","start"]
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

When the container starts it does start with the right command -

```
newkeyz-web | > newkeyz@1.9.5 start /home/meteor/app
newkeyz-web | > MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor meteor --settings settings.json
```

But the meteor app still tries to connect to the local mongodb instance

`MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:3001]`

I've tried all the different ways of specifying the mongo_url in the command

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor && meteor --settings settings.json

MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor meteor --settings settings.json

meteor --settings settings.json
```

I even have a ENV in the Dockerfile but no luck

`ENV MONGO_URL mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor`

What am i doing wrong? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The agenda npm init code was trying to connect to the local db based on a different environment variable.

```
export const agenda = new Agenda({
  maxConcurrency: 1,
  db: {
    address: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  },
});
```

After changing it to the right variable it worked.

Comment: I would not consider this as an answer. You must give detailed description and little insight with code and configuration example, which you have not specified. It is good that you found out the answer but your answer will not help anyone.